# Unable to swipe images

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code in viewDidLoad method.

```
  [self.zoomImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"imageUrl"];
    NSLog(@"saved %@",savedValue);

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [self.zoomImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.zoomImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

I want the user to swipe back and forth the images. But swipeLeft and swipeRight methods are not being called. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set delegate `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` and add following code

```
swipeLeft.delegate = self;
swipeRight.delegate = self; 

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{ 
      return YES; 
}
```

Comment: self.zoomImage is your imageView ?

Comment: @Learner check the subview of it and set [self.subview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Comment: try adding gesture on view insted of imageView, it worked for me